# Incompatible pointer types assigning to NSObject<MGTwitterEngineDelegate> *__weak from NSObject

Tags: iphone, ios5, weak-references, mgtwitterengine

"Incompatible pointer types assigning to NSObject *__weak from NSObject"

When using MGTwitterEngine I get this error. If I turn off "treat warnings as errors" it seems to skip over. Why is this happening?

`__weak NSObject <MGTwitterEngineDelegate> *_delegate;`

When I tried removing the __weak I got more errors.

Comment: What are you assigning to `_delegate`?

Comment: It turns out that including <MGTwitterEngineDelegate> in the method signature fixes the issue.

Comment: @quantumpotato , In which part of the signature? An example?

Comment: - (id)initWithXML:(NSData *)theXML delegate:(NSObject <MGTwitterParserDelegate>*)theDelegate 
connectionIdentifier:(NSString *)theIdentifier requestType:(MGTwitterRequestType)reqType

instead of

- (id)initWithXML:(NSData *)theXML delegate:(NSObject *)theDelegate 
connectionIdentifier:(NSString *)theIdentifier requestType:(MGTwitterRequestType)reqType 
  responseType:(MGTwitterResponseType)respType URL:(NSURL *)theURL
 
  responseType:(MGTwitterResponseType)respType URL:(NSURL *)theURL
{

Comment: I added <MGTwitterParserDelegate> to the signature for the delegate. 

This is inMGTwitterLibXMLParser, but I did this in all occurances of (NSObject *)theDelegate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`- (id)initWithXML:(NSData *)theXML delegate:(NSObject *)theDelegate 
connectionIdentifier:(NSString *)theIdentifier requestType:(MGTwitterRequestType)reqType 
     responseType:(MGTwitterResponseType)respType URL:(NSURL *)theURL`

becomes

`- (id)initWithXML:(NSData *)theXML delegate:(NSObject <MGTwitterParserDelegate>*)theDelegate 
connectionIdentifier:(NSString *)theIdentifier requestType:(MGTwitterRequestType)reqType 
     responseType:(MGTwitterResponseType)respType URL:(NSURL *)theURL
{`

And replace similar instances of NSObject delegates, usually in init methods, throughout the MGTwitterEngine.

Comment: Is that last } bracket a typo?

Answer (score 4):

Try use `__unsafe_unretained id` instead of using `__weak NSObject*`

Comment: That.. got further than before. Going to mark as correct, it compiled.

Comment: (Eventually it still crashes! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673753/mgtwitterengine-delegate-deallocated-by-the-time-connectiondidfinishloading-cal )

Comment: It turns out that including <MGTwitterEngineDelegate> in the method signature fixes the issue. 

What does __unsafe_unretained do?